# Where to find TreeListViews ColumnHeaderClick Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, treelistview

I'm developing a tool which shows data from a database in a hierarchical manner. As there are additional data for each item I'm using a TreeListView control to display them in additional columns. The number of columns is determined by user input.

The custom control that I'm using is Ricciolos TreeListView:
http://windowsclient.net/blogs/ricciolocristian/archive/2008/03/22/a-complete-wpf-treelistview-control.aspx

My problem now is, that I need to catch the ColumnHeaderClick event to apply a sorting logic. I already interviewed auntie Google, but no results.
Maybe somene here knows where to find such an event and how to determine which column header has been clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Isnt there a generic click event with parameters telling where the click 'landed'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a handler for the GridViewColumnHeader.Click event. This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fe97254b-6f6c-4e2c-b83d-6f83567598cc) describes how to do it for the ListView, which uses the same underlying controls. This code was adapted from that link:

```
myTreeListView.AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnGridViewColumnHeaderClicked));

private void OnGridViewColumnHeaderClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("testing");
}
```

Alternatively, you can attach a handler via XAML like so:

```
<my:TreeListView GridViewColumnHeader.Click="OnGridViewColumnHeaderClicked" />
```

The e.OriginalSource will include the GridViewColumnHeader, and e.Source/sender would be the TreeListView.